# can the parameters FromUri be read from an attribute?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, custom-attributes

I have a simple controller that accepts a response from a payment system.

```
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Pending([FromUri] DepositResponse response)
        {
            Logger.LogInfo(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));

            return Ok(response);
        }
```

the deposit response however has very ugly and unstandardised parameters. I have no control over that because that's what the payment system sends.

```
public class DepositResponse
{
    public string ppp_status { get; set; }

    public string ExErrorCode { get; set; }

    public string PPP_TransactionID { get; set; }

    public string merchant_site_id { get; set; }

    //etc
}
```

As a result, Resharper complains about the chosen name that it doesn't match the rules and I want to change it to match all the classes in the rest of the project.

Is there an attribute I can use, or one I can create to make `FromUri` understand the response?

For example

```
public class DepositResponse
{
    [FromUriName("ppp_status")]
    public string pppStatus { get; set; }

    [FromUriName("ExErrorCode")]
    public string exErrorCode { get; set; }

    [FromUriName("PPP_TransactionID")]
    public string pppTransactionId { get; set; }

    [FromUriName("merchant_site_id")]
    public string merchantSiteId { get; set; }

    //etc
}
```

I couldn't find such an example online, but I would imagine it can be very useful when dealing with external systems that send rubbish...

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below model

```
public class DepositResponse
    {

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="ppp_status")]
    public string pppStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="ExErrorCode")]
    public string exErrorCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="PPP_TransactionID")]
    public string pppTransactionId { get; set; }

    [PropertyName(PropertyName="merchant_site_id")]
    public string merchantSiteId { get; set; }

    //etc
    }
```

Comment: This, of course, doesn't work. Did you try it?
I am doing an HTTP Get, so the parameters need to match the name of the property exactly.
My solution would involve some custom binder, or an extension to "FromUri".